# Saving json for loop

Tags: json

Any concise was to save for loop in json format? Thank you for your help.

```
import requests
import json

results = []

for i in range(1,143):
    res = requests.get("https://www.bhhs.com/bin/bhhs/officeSearchServlet?PageSize=10&Sort=1&Page={}&office_country=US".format(i))
    results.append(res.json())

# What goes next? Thank you!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your job is much easier now. The website uses javascript to get this information.

The below scrapes all the 141 pages.

```
import requests, json

results = []

for i in range(1,142):
    res = requests.get("https://www.bhhs.com/bin/bhhs/officeSearchServlet?PageSize=10&Sort=1&Page={}&office_country=US".format(i))
    results.append(res.json())

with open("result.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(results, f)
```

Trying all the requests at once can make some requests failed. Hence, I recommend crawling the pages in batches and save the data like pages from 1-10 save the data, next 10-20 save the data etc... Next you can consolidate all the scraped results

Comment: @JacksonWilshire May be some requests failed. I try the same script in my ipython terminal. It's working fine in my jupyter notebook .See for which page that error is occurring

Comment: @JacksonWilshire No, it's not there. That's why I have added updated my answer.

Comment: Going through the Chrome Developer tools. @JacksonWilshire Upvote and accept the answer if it has helped you